# Tracking current displayed fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am adding several fragments in one fragment activity, is there a way to get which fragment is currently visible to the user after I have clicked my back button?

I have tried to do this by saving the tag of the current fragment in preferences and then when  I update it when the back button is pressed. It's a but tedious but it works. However I feel it is better to use any methods provided by the system.

Unfortunately onResume and onStart don't seem to work for fragments in this scenario.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Several could be visible - or you could use action bar tabs and a tab listener which can manage this for you. In what way do onStart and onResume not work ?

Comment: no start and resume don't work because I don't hind previous fragment I just place another pone in front of it

Comment: If you attach / detach fragments dynamically then you have to manage this yourself. Would an approach based on static fragments (xml) work in your case ?

Answer (score 0):

I also facing this situation in my work:
I do it like this:

subclass of fragment activity to manage the the push and pop

```
public class KFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private KFragment currentFragment;


//add new fragment
public void pushFragment(Class clz) {

  //fragment = new fragement instance;
  //hold the current instance
  currentFragment = fragment;
}


//
public void popTopFragment() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    currentFragment = null;
    int cnt = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (cnt > 0) {
        String name = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(cnt - 1).getName();
                    //hold current instance
        currentFragment = (KFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(name);
        currentFragment.onBackFailed(null);
    }
   }

 }
```